# django-admin-tools 0.8 after installing and configuring shows error 404 while trying to open admin page

Tags: python, django, django-admin-tools

I had installed and configured django-admin-tools 0.8 following the documentation. Django version is 1.11.4, using virtualenv in project.

File settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'admin_tools',
    'admin_tools.theming',
    'admin_tools.menu',
    'admin_tools.dashboard',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'atelierapp',
]

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    #'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'django.core.context_processors.request',
        ],
        'loaders': [
            'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
            'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
            'admin_tools.template_loaders.Loader',
        ]
    },
},
]
```

File urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    #url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^admin_tools/', include('admin_tools.urls')),
]
```

But when I try to enter the admin panel, I get a 404 error.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5OIO.png)

What is the problem I'm not seeing? 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: add '/'  in last of URL according to snapshot

Comment: It still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation

> Prerequisite
>   In order to use django-admin-tools you obviously need to have configured your Django admin site. If you didn’t, please refer to the relevant django documentation.

However I noticed in your urls that you have:

```
#url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

Have you tried removing the # tag?

Comment: I have configured my Django admin site. Yes, I have tried to remove the # tag. It also didn’t work.

Comment: Anastasia are you using any sort of styling template structure such as bootstrap etc? If so, are you compressing your static files?  I recently introduced a bootstrap template to one of my sites and compressing the static files was causing me to get a similar error.  I'm wondering if the issue is related to your static files rather than the admin-tools stuff.

Comment: I don’t use bootstrap and others, only python Django on this step of project.

Comment: And you have all your static folders set properly with the right permissions?

Comment: It is not a problem with static folders, but yes, I have set properly all static folders with the right permissions.